# Common type of lambdas with same signature and captures

Tags: c++, c++11, types, lambda, c++14

Let's say I have some lambdas with **exactly the same captures** and **exactly the same signatures**.

```
int captured;
auto l0 = [&captured](int x){ captured += x; }; 
auto l1 = [&captured](int x){ captured -= x; };
auto l2 = [&captured](int x){ captured = x + 1; };
```

Now, let's say I need to store these lambdas in an `std::vector`, to call them at runtime.

I cannot use a raw function pointer, as the captured variable forces the lambda to be a functor, rather than a conventional function.

I could use `std::function`, but it's overkill, since I know for sure that all the lambdas have the same signature and the same captures. Since `std::function` supports lambdas with same signature **but different captures**, I'm *(very probably)* paying an additional runtime cost that could be *(?)* avoided.

```
std::vector<decltype(l0)> v0; // Ok
v0.emplace_back(l0);          // Ok
v1.emplace_back(l1);          // Nope: `decltype(l0) != decltype(l1)`
v2.emplace_back(l2);          // Nope: `decltype(l0) != decltype(l2)`
```

I would like something to find out a common type between all lambdas, but `std::common_type` does not work.

```
// Nope: does not compile
using LCT = std::common_type_t<decltype(l0), decltype(l1), decltype(l2)>;
```

Basically, **I need something between a raw function pointer and `std::function`.** Does anything like that exist? And...  can anything like that be actually implemented?

Comment: Each lambda has a unique class type unrelated to anything else.  Even the same lambda expression written twice has different types. If the number of possible lambda types is finite, consider a tagged union.

Comment: *"very probably"*  does not sound like you found out that `std::function` is too slow for your use-case through measurement...

Comment: @T.C.: I understand what you say. But instinctively it seems to me that `l0`, `l1` and `l2` do have the same memory layout (though it's probably not guaranteed by the standard). What bothers me is, if I'm correct about the lambdas having the same memory layout, that there is no way (unless using an extremely unsafe `reinterpret_cast` or paying an extra price by using `std::function`) to group them together.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Indeed, I didn't. Consider this question purely from a theoretical point of view and a curiosity about the language.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo By *exactly the same captures* do you mean just the same form for the list of captures declared between `[]`, or is it that all the lambdas that you want to store in that vector will capture the *exact same variables*, with the *exact same values*, so each closure object will actually store the same data values, and storing those values for each object is redundant?

Comment: @bogdan: The latter.

Comment: Why not move to capture-free lambdas, and then explicitly pass in `captured` by reference to the lambda? Then you have a vector of pointers to simple two-args functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, I think this is (very roughly) what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename L, typename R, typename... Args> struct lambda_hack
{
    using storage_type = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(L), std::alignment_of<L>::value>;
    static storage_type storage;
    static void init_data(const L& arg) { new(&storage) L(arg); }
    template<typename LL> static R call_target(Args... args) { return reinterpret_cast<LL&>(storage)(args...); }

    template<typename LL> lambda_hack(LL&&) : target(call_target<LL>) { }
    using target_type = R(*)(Args...);
    target_type target;
    R operator()(Args... args) const { return target(args...); }
};

template<typename L, typename R, typename... Args> 
typename lambda_hack<L, R, Args...>::storage_type lambda_hack<L, R, Args...>::storage;

int main()
{
    int captured = 7;
    auto l0 = [&captured](int x){ captured += x; }; 
    auto l1 = [&captured](int x){ captured -= x; };
    auto l2 = [&captured](int x){ captured = x + 1; };

    using lhack = lambda_hack<decltype(l0), void, int>;
    lhack::init_data(l0);
    std::vector<lhack> v{l0, l1, l2};
    for(auto& h : v)
    {
        std::cout << "'captured' before: " << captured << '\n';
        h(3);
        std::cout << "'captured' after: " << captured << '\n' << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << captured << '\n'; // prints '4', as expected
}
```

The functor stored in the `std::vector` is just the size of one non-member function pointer. The actual captured data is stored separately, only once. Calling `operator()` on such a functor has the overhead of just one indirection through that pointer (better than a virtual function call).

It compiles and runs on GCC 4.9.1 and Clang 3.5.0 in C++14 mode, and VC++ 2013.

Consider this to be an **alpha version** of what you would actually use in production. It needs refining (for example, it doesn't destroy the static storage properly). I'd like to first see if this is indeed what you were looking for.

The first thing to address is probably the fact that `storage` shouldn't be `static`. Since a set of such lambdas will be inherently very closely related, you'll probably want to store them in a container, as you mentioned in the question. Since `storage` needs to be available for as long as that container lives, I'd store it in the container itself (subclass `std::vector`, maybe?...) and destroy its contents when the container is destroyed.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll try it out when I have some free time and share my results. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried your code out both with **gcc 4.9.2** and **clang 3.5**. I've benchmarked it against `std::function`, using `-O3 -DNDEBUG`. Unfortunately, it seems that the performance of your code is almost identical to `std::function` - I guess the compiler can optimize away the virtual calls?

Comment: I've also tried storing a reference to `storage` per `LambdaHack` instance and also storing the `storage` itself in the instances. Results did not change.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo As far as I know, there are good implementations of `std::function` that only require one call through a function pointer for `operator()`, just like my solution. In the worst case, it's a virtual function call or something similar (two indirections), which is clearly slower, but not catastropically so. I'm not sure, but I think `libstdc++` has this optimization. So, the performance of the function call itself is likely to be the same or relatively close. I don't think you can do any better and still have a reasonably general solution.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo However, the purpose of the exercise was to take advantage of the fact that the data stored in the closure object is the same for all lambdas, and only store it once. This should show up for reasonably sized arrays (start with one million entries, for example, this should make things visible enough) and, especially, for not-so-small captures (make it, at least 32 bytes on a 32-bit machine). The first thing that should show up is the difference in heap allocations: my solution doesn't have any, while `std::function` needs to store each closure object individually on the heap.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Everything should fit in the cache much better as well for my solution when iterating over the vector and calling the functor. After all, it's only one pointer, while a `std::function` object is larger, and the closure object data itself is just 32 bytes in one place, compared to 32 MB that need to be scanned each time (not to mention they might not be sequential, since they're separate heap allocations - depends on your allocation pattern). Moving things around in the array (reordering calls) should show a difference in performance as well, but maybe not as large.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I think these are the kinds of scenarios where you should expect to see a difference in performance. This is what you asked for - to take advantage of the common data in the closure objects, but keep the ability to call different functions on that data, all using lambda expression notation. Any further optimization would require getting rid of the function pointer, and I think the only way to do that in general is to know at compile time what functors are going to be called and in what order, but that's a different problem that has nothing to do with `std::function`.

Answer (score 6):

C++ Standard section § 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] :

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a **unique**, unnamed non union class type — called the closure type

Each lambda has a different type : `l0`, `l1` and `l2` have no common type.

So consider either a `std::vector<>` of a variant type, e.g. [boost.variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) (if you know the set of the lambda types), or use `std::function<>`, which seems appropriate here too.

---

**Example** with [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) :

```
int main () {
    int captured = 42;
    auto l0 = [&captured](int x){ captured += x; }; 
    auto l1 = [&captured](int x){ captured -= x; };
    auto l2 = [&captured](int x){ captured = x + 1; };

    std::vector<boost::variant< decltype(l0), decltype(l1), decltype(l2)>> variant;
    variant.push_back(l0);
    variant.push_back(l1);
    variant.push_back(l2);

    auto f =  boost::get<decltype(l1)>(variant[1]);

    int i = 1;
    f(i);
    std::cout << captured;
}
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed5d1de81744a00b)**

**Note:**

As pointed by Johannes Schaub, a lambda variant like this one is not default constructible, i.e. you cant write :

```
boost::variant< decltype(l0), decltype(l1), decltype(l2)> v;
```

Whereas `std::function<>` are default constructible..

Comment: I would like to draw attention to the fact that `variant` cannot be ["empty"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty), and for such a lambda-variant therefore it is not default-constructible. For `std::function` you will be able to default-construct it.

Answer (score 2):

Remember what a lambda is: shorthand for a function object which could be written by hand in C++98.

Your three lambdas are equivalent to the following:

```
int captured;

struct l0_t {
    int& captured;
    l0_t(int& _captured) : captured(_captured) {}
    void operator()(int x) const { captured += x; }
} l0(captured);

struct l1_t {
    int& captured;
    l1_t(int& _captured) : captured(_captured) {}
    void operator()(int x) const { captured -= x; }
} l1(captured);

struct l2_t {
    int& captured;
    l2_t(int& _captured) : captured(_captured) {}
    void operator()(int x) const { captured = x + 1; }
} l2(captured);
```

Given that, if you want to be able to treat these three objects polymorphically, then you need some kind of virtual dispatch, and that is exactly what `std::function` or `boost::variant` would give you.

If you were willing to move away from lambdas, a simpler solution would be a single class with three different member functions, and a `vector` of pointers to member functions of that class, given that there's no reason for every element of the vector to have its own reference to the captured object:

```
struct f {
    int& captured;
    f(int& _captured) : captured(_captured) {}
    void f0(int x) const { captured += x; }
    void f1(int x) const { captured -= x; }
    void f2(int x) const { captured = x + 1; }
};

int captured = 0;
f multiplex(captured);
std::vector<decltype(&f::f0)> fv { &f::f0, &f::f1, &f::f2 };
for (auto&& fn : fv) {
    (multiplex.*fn)(42);
    std::cout << captured << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not exist.

You can use `std::function`.  You can use `boost::variant`.  Or you can write your own type erasure type.

A `one_of_these_function` that stores a `boost::variant` or reimplements it, and exposes a particular `operator()` signature that uses a visitor on the variant to invoke the right method would solve your problem reasonably efficiently.

Another slightly insane option would be writing your own function like class based off "fastest possible delegates" techniques, presume that the above lambdas are the size of one pointer and can be treated as trivially copyable and use tomfoolery to pseudo-store them and invoke `operator()` on a pointer to said stored pointer.  I can tell you it works, but it may not be polite to the language.